# Apache .htaccess rewrite rules to NGINX converted rules not effective

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite

I'm running a website "PHP script" on aaPanel with Debian 10 installed. All works ok but the images are not showing/broken

The /image/ path is a rewrite rule, and it resolves to image.php which loads the image from the uploads folder. after converting .htaccess to Nginx and add them to the system all image paths going to

```
www.website.com/image/m/112/112/335757712_1152702765_706821275.jpeg
```

The actual path should be

```
www.website.com/uploads/media/112/112/335757712_1152702765_706821275.jpeg
```

**Below are the .htaccess rules**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)                                       $1                                              [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)?$                               index.php?a=$1                                  [L]

RewriteRule ^welcome/?$                                 index.php?a=welcome                             [NC]

RewriteRule ^stream/?$                                  index.php?a=stream                              [NC]
RewriteRule ^stream/logout$                             index.php?a=stream&logout                       [NC]

RewriteRule ^explore/?$                                 index.php?a=explore                             [NC]
RewriteRule ^explore/filter/([^/]+)/?$                  index.php?a=explore&filter=$1                   [NC]
RewriteRule ^explore/popular$                           index.php?a=explore&popular                     [NC]
RewriteRule ^explore/liked$                             index.php?a=explore&liked                       [NC]

RewriteRule ^history/?$                                 index.php?a=history                             [NC]

RewriteRule ^upload/?$                                  index.php?a=upload                              [NC]

RewriteRule ^pro/?$                                     index.php?a=pro                                 [NC]

RewriteRule ^stats/?$                                   index.php?a=stats                               [NC]
RewriteRule ^stats/filter/([^/]+)/?$                    index.php?a=stats&filter=$1                     [NC]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$                         index.php?a=profile&u=$1                        [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$                 index.php?a=profile&u=$1&r=$2                   [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/filter/([^/]+)/?$          index.php?a=profile&u=$1&filter=$2              [NC]

RewriteRule ^notifications/?$                           index.php?a=notifications                       [NC]
RewriteRule ^notifications/filter/([^/]+)/?$            index.php?a=notifications&filter=$1             [NC]

RewriteRule ^settings/?$                                index.php?a=settings                            [NC]
RewriteRule ^settings/([^/]+)/?$                        index.php?a=settings&b=$1                       [NC]

RewriteRule ^messages/?$                                index.php?a=messages                            [NC]
RewriteRule ^messages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$                index.php?a=messages&u=$1&id=$2                 [NC]

RewriteRule ^track/([^/]+)/?$                           index.php?a=track&id=$1                         [NC]
RewriteRule ^track/([^/]+)/edit/?$                      index.php?a=track&id=$1&type=edit               [NC]
RewriteRule ^track/([^/]+)/report/?$                    index.php?a=track&id=$1&type=report             [NC]
RewriteRule ^track/([^/]+)/stats/?$                     index.php?a=track&id=$1&type=stats              [NC]
RewriteRule ^track/([^/]+)/likes/?$                     index.php?a=track&id=$1&type=likes              [NC]
RewriteRule ^track/([^/]+)/stats/filter/([^/]+)/?$      index.php?a=track&id=$1&type=stats&filter=$2    [NC]
RewriteRule ^track/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$                   index.php?a=track&id=$1&name=$2                 [NC]

RewriteRule ^playlist/([^/]+)/?$                        index.php?a=playlist&id=$1                      [NC]
RewriteRule ^playlist/([^/]+)/edit/?$                   index.php?a=playlist&id=$1&edit=true            [NC]
RewriteRule ^playlist/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$                index.php?a=playlist&id=$1&name=$2              [NC]

RewriteRule ^search/filter/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$           index.php?a=search&filter=$1&q=$2               [NC]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$                            index.php?a=page&b=$1                           [NC]

RewriteRule ^recover/?$                                 index.php?a=recover                             [NC]
RewriteRule ^recover/do/?$                              index.php?a=recover&r=1                         [NC]

RewriteRule ^image/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$   image.php?t=$1&w=$2&h=$3&src=$4
```

**Below are the Nginx converted rules**

```
location / {
  if (-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
  }
  rewrite ^/(([^/]*)+)?$ /index.php?a=$1 break;
}

location /welcome {
  rewrite ^/welcome/?$ /index.php?a=welcome;
}

location /stream {
  rewrite ^/stream/?$ /index.php?a=stream;
}

location = /stream/logout {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?a=stream&logout;
}

location /explore {
  rewrite ^/explore/?$ /index.php?a=explore;
  rewrite ^/explore/filter/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=explore&filter=$1;
}

location = /explore/popular {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?a=explore&popular;
}

location = /explore/liked {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?a=explore&liked;
}

location /history {
  rewrite ^/history/?$ /index.php?a=history;
}

location /upload {
  rewrite ^/upload/?$ /index.php?a=upload;
}

location /pro {
  rewrite ^/pro/?$ /index.php?a=pro;
}

location /stats {
  rewrite ^/stats/?$ /index.php?a=stats;
  rewrite ^/stats/filter/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=stats&filter=$1;
}

location /profile {
  rewrite ^/profile/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1;
  rewrite ^/profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1&r=$2;
  rewrite ^/profile/([^/]+)/filter/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1&filter=$2;
}

location /notifications {
  rewrite ^/notifications/?$ /index.php?a=notifications;
  rewrite ^/notifications/filter/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=notifications&filter=$1;
}

location /settings {
  rewrite ^/settings/?$ /index.php?a=settings;
  rewrite ^/settings/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=settings&b=$1;
}

location /messages {
  rewrite ^/messages/?$ /index.php?a=messages;
  rewrite ^/messages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=messages&u=$1&id=$2;
}

location /track {
  rewrite ^/track/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=track&id=$1;
  rewrite ^/track/([^/]+)/edit/?$ /index.php?a=track&id=$1&type=edit;
  rewrite ^/track/([^/]+)/report/?$ /index.php?a=track&id=$1&type=report;
  rewrite ^/track/([^/]+)/stats/?$ /index.php?a=track&id=$1&type=stats;
  rewrite ^/track/([^/]+)/likes/?$ /index.php?a=track&id=$1&type=likes;
  rewrite ^/track/([^/]+)/stats/filter/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=track&id=$1&type=stats&filter=$2;
  rewrite ^/track/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=track&id=$1&name=$2;
}

location /playlist {
  rewrite ^/playlist/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=playlist&id=$1;
  rewrite ^/playlist/([^/]+)/edit/?$ /index.php?a=playlist&id=$1&edit=true;
  rewrite ^/playlist/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=playlist&id=$1&name=$2;
}

location /search {
  rewrite ^/search/filter/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=search&filter=$1&q=$2;
}

location /page {
  rewrite ^/page/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=page&b=$1;
}

location /recover {
  rewrite ^/recover/?$ /index.php?a=recover;
  rewrite ^/recover/do/?$ /index.php?a=recover&r=1;
}

location /image {
  rewrite ^/image/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /image.php?t=$1&w=$2&h=$3&src=$4;
}
```

I'm confused and I can't think of anything to figure this out.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rewrite rule convertors are quite bad usually. It is better to implement then in native nginx way. In this case, the `image` location would be as follows:

```
location ~ ^/image/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ {
    try_files /image.php?t=$1&w=$2&h=$3&src=$4 =404;
}
```

BTW. I hope your `image.php` has proper input validation for width / height, so that attacker cannot DDoS your server by asking 1M x 1M version of an image...

Comment: Yes, I agree with the rewrite converters. You gave me the correct rule. after adding the rule now all my images came back to life :) Thank you so much for this answer. I learned something new today.

Comment: A `rewrite` instead is much better in this situation. The `image.php` exists always. There's no point in checking the file existence with the `try_files`..

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between `try_files` and `rewrite` here. Both try to open the file, only error case handling is different.